# Migration path for Fql.multiquery

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I'm new to Facebook development. I'm working on migrating an existing app in accordance to the Graph API upgrade guide.  I'm looking for guidance around calls such as api.facebook.com/method/Fql.multiquery.

My question is: does this type of API need to be upgraded as well, or does it only apply to graph.facebook.com calls?  I want to ensure that api.facebook.com/method/Fql.multiquery calls will still work after 4/30/15.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to take a look at the [Batch Requests](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/making-multiple-requests) of the Graph API. You can also [specify dependencies](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/making-multiple-requests#operations) between the requests.

Answer (score 0):

Calls to http://api.facebook.com/method/Fql.multiquery will no longer work. The REST API is long deprecated anyway.

As @luschn said, you have to migrate to the Graph APIs batch requests, and use the `/fql` endpoint. You can only use FQL if you have a v2.0 app, and not higher.